# how to display only an element of a list of list but not all the lists of the list in html?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a list containing all the chapters of a book, so when I click on chapter title, I want to display only paragraph titles of the selected chapter.
My problem is when I  click chapter title, I display all paragraph titles for all the chapters.
Here's My code:
Html:

```
<ul class="summary">

  <!--{#On va choisir un summary avec class.selected pour développer information correspondante#}-->
  <li *ngFor = "let summary of resume ; let i=index" (click) = "onSelect(summary);changePage(summary.page.index,1);total() " [class.selected=""]="summary===selectedSum">
    <span >
      <strong>{{i+1}}-{{summary.titre}}</strong>
      <span class="endline">  P.{{summary.page.index }}</span>
    </span>

    <div>
      <ul class="summary.page.paragraphs">
        <li *ngIf ="check"  style="margin:auto">{{resume[i].page.paragraphs[4].content}}</li>
        <!--<li  style="margin:auto"><strong>{{summary.page.paragraphs[5].content}}</strong> </li>-->
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: add snippet to your question

Comment: I assume this is toggled with `check`, which naturally opens all. You need to have a unique variable. Maybe insert a new property in your object, a boolean property that you toggle false/true for that single object only. Impossible to help further since we have no idea how your data looks like, so it's quite hard to figure what's going on, or where you are toggling this... at least to me it looks confusing :)